# ruby regular expression grouping

Tags: ruby, regex, grouping

I am having a problem extracting a substring from a string using regex.

For example I have a string like follows

```
str = "result[cars][ford]"
```

Now I need a regex which can extract out cars and ford out of that string so that when

```
str.match({{regex}})[1]
```

would provide cars and

```
str.match({{regex}})[2]
```

would provide ford

Now i need that regex inside that curly braces.

Any link that helps to this question are most welcomed.

Comment: Question updated: str always must start with result

Comment: Well, your string doesn't match this condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually simple.

```
s = "result[cars][ford]"
matches = s.scan(/\[(\w+)\]/).flatten # => ["cars", "ford"]
```

Here's a [demo](http://rubular.com/r/kdtvrB8HiF).

Comment: Hi, Sergio Tulentsev please see the comment in question.

Comment: Well here's what i got with this regex. str = "result[cars][ford]". str.match(/\[(\w+)\]/)[2] gives me nil

Comment: Still it produce the same result for the string str = "whatever[cars][ford]". matches = str.scan(/\[(\w+)\]/).flatten # => ["cars", "ford"]. How do i get the result only if it starts with **result**